# "Column "parent_id" for "cte" is specified more than once" in SQL recursive query

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query

I have 5 SQL tables with columns as follows:

```
tbl_request_listEmpB
listEmpB_id request_id

tbl_request_listEmpD
listEmpD_id request_id

tbl_employee
id, parent_id (this one refers to id in tbl_department)

tbl_department
id, parent_id (that one referes to id of parent department)

tbl_department_manager
department_id, manager_employee_id
```

As input data I have `employee_id` and `request_id`.

I need to figure out whether the employee has access to the request (whether he's a manager or not)

Here's the query which is supposed to return 1 if the current user is a manager, 0 otherwise

```
 with reqEmployees as (
    select listEmpB_id as employee_id
    from tbl_request_listEmpB
    where request_id = ${request_id}
  union all --concatenate the two tables
    select listEmpD_id
    from tbl_request_listEmpD
    where  request_id = ${request_id}
),
cte as (
    select e.parent_id, null as parent_id
    from reqEmployees r
    join tbl_employee e  on e.id = r.employee_id -- get these employees' departments
    union all
    select d.id, d.parent_id
    from cte
    join tbl_department d on d.id = cte.parent_id    -- and get parent departments
)
select case when exists (select 1
    from cte  
    join tbl_department_manager dm on dm.department_id = cte.id
    where dm.manager_employee_id = ${employee_id})
  then 1 else 0 end;
```

Finally, there's the logic that I believe is implemented in the query above:

1. First we need to identify whether the `employee_id` is a manager or not. If he is - find in which departments. So we query to `tbl_department_manager` based on `manager_employee_id(=employee_id from input data)` to get a list of corresponding `department_id` and store them in a variable. If the query returned 0 departments - terminate and return false
2. Based on `request_id` we collect ids of employees from both `tbl_request_listEmpB` and `tbl_request_listEmpD`. Later we refer to them as `employee_id` from `reqEmployees`
3. Query to `tbl_employee` based on ids retrieved from p.2 to get `parent_id` (list of unique departments employees belong to)
4. If there's a match between at least one department from p.1 and a one from p.3 return true
5. If not, there's a need to query to `tbl_department` and recursively search for a match between at least one element from p.1 and one element in p.3.parent_id

Here's what I mean

Consider the following chart

[image]

And here's the corresponding SQL table:

```
tbl_department (id, parent_id)
dep0   null
dep1   dep0
dep2   dep1
dep3   dep1
dep4   dep2
dep5   dep0
```

So, if we have a departments list returned from p.1 of `['dep1']` (there might be more than one element, we have to iterate through each element) we need to return true ONLY if from p.3 we've got `dep1|dep2|dep3|dep4 - (dep1 descendants including dep1)`. If `['dep2']` return true if `dep2|dep4`. So there should at least one match of at least one element from p.1 and recursive result from p.5. I hope I illustrated it in the clearest way possible

Almost forgot - the query above gives me

```
"Column "parent_id" for "cte" is specified more than once"
```

But I don't think that it does what it's supposed to do, I need to rewrite it

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Would you please share sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without some sample data (and parameter values) and expected output for that data (with those parameter values), it's difficult to verify this solution.

I have assumed that your `tbl_ou` and `tbl_department` are in fact the same table.

Other than the CTE, it looks like the rest of your code should work. The CTE below now travels "both" directions through the hierarchy (upwards and downwards), finding both parents and children. Note that it only finds parents of parents and children of children, it doesn't find children of parents, for example, so no "siblings", "uncles" or whatever these records should be called!

You may need to cast both fields in the CTE seed record as the relevant data type. Based on the supplied data I have assumed that the datatype for department `id` (and therefore also for `parent_id`) is `varchar(10)`.

```
cte as (
select
    cast(e.parent_id as varchar(10)) as id,
    cast(o.parent_id as varchar(10)) as parent_id,
    0 as iteration  
from
    reqEmployees r
    join tbl_employee e  on e.id = r.employee_id
    join tbl_department o on e.parent_id = o.id 
    --extra table here compared to earlier versions to allow us
    --to traverse hierarchy in both directions

union all

select --This one finds "child" departments
    o.id,
    o.parent_id,
    cte.iteration + 1
from
    cte
    join tbl_department o on o.id = cte.parent_id
where    
    cte.iteration >=0 --prevents siblings/uncles etc

union all

select --This one finds "parent" departments
    o.id,
    o.parent_id,
    cte.iteration - 1
from
    cte
    join tbl_department o on o.parent_id = cte.id 
where    
    cte.iteration <=0 --prevents siblings/uncles etc
  
)
```

You can test my script using this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/79af4/2/0) (updated).

Comment: It gives me `Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column “parent_id” of recursive query “cte”`

Comment: `NULL` is a valid value for many data types and it needs to be set in the "seed". I've reworked the code to `CAST` the `NULL` as an `INT`. But you'll need it to agree with the datatype of your parent_id field. Based on the example data, that may be `varchar(10)` or  similar.

Comment: Based on other parts of your code, you may be better with an alias of `id` rather than `dept_id`. Also, I'm not convinced we are climbing the department hierarchy correctly

Comment: I've made some changes to reflect my previous comment. But perhaps these are not the correct changes. Do you want to travel up the heirarchy or down it in the CTE? Find all the parents or all the children?

Comment: I need the most optimised solution - if the query from p.4 didn't return true - there's a need to travel down the hierarchy

Comment: I've added a version of the cte which traverses the org unit table in the opposite direction. You can check what each one is doing by running `SELECT * FROM cte` instead of your `SELECT CASE` statement.

Comment: Is there a way to somehow output which departments I get with each iteration in cte?

Comment: I've just added an "iteration" field to the CTE, which counts which iteration you are on. I trust this is what you're meaning. Obviously, you then just select from the CTE at the end as per my previous comment.

Comment: Unfortunately, the cte returned 0 instead of 1, even though there's a parent. For simplicity I've assigned `employee(1,2)`, `department(3,4)` and `request(5)` in the following fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4634b2/2 . Department 4 is a child of 3

Comment: So, it doesn't work even with 1 deepness level

Comment: @JoeD, In your fiddle, I think you had inserted values into `tbl_request_listEmpB` in the wrong order. Swapped over, the CTE finds records ... perhaps still not the right ones. It's looking for parent records not child records at present. I'm still not that sure which you want.

Comment: Yes, I did. I accidentally mixed up `tbl_request_listEmpB`. It's supposed to be `(1,5) (employee_id, request_id)`

Comment: In the fiddle found department from employee is `3`. `4` is a child of `3`. Manager is of `4` department - a child of `3` - so it should return 1

Comment: It will do that if you traverse the hierarchy in the opposite direction, finding children rather than parents. I'll update my answer shortly.

Comment: Thank you. Also, the query in the fiddle should return 1 in case if found department from employee is either `3` or `4` (parent or children)

Comment: I appreciate your time, patience and effort - your latest query finally did the trick! Thank you so much, I hope someday I'll be able to write such sophisticated queries myself, instead of bothering others. Have a good day!